# PHP doesn't store data in array on HTTP request from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm passing an array to a PHP file via this JavaScript method:

```
/**
 * The PHP file which receives the data
 *
 * @type {string} The php filename
 */
const INSTALL_FILE = "install.php";

/**
 * Passes roadTaxData to the php install file which could be get with the $_POST operator
 */
function passToPHP (paramName, data) {
    var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity"
    httpc.open("POST", INSTALL_FILE, true); // sending as POST

    httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    /*
     Test purposes
     */
    httpc.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
        if (httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) { // complete and no errors
            console.log(httpc.responseText); // some processing here, or whatever you want to do with the response
        }
    };
    httpc.send(paramName + "=" + data);
}
```

In my PHP file which is receiving data (it does, i'm calling the method and actually tested it) i have something like this:

```
$road_tax_data = json_decode($_POST['road-tax_data'], true);
require "RoadTaxDataParser.php";

RoadTaxDataParser::set('test', $road_tax_data);
```

Which reffers to this file:

```
class RoadTaxDataParser
{
    private static $data = [];

    public static function set ($key, $value) {
        self::$data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function get ($key) {
        return self::$data[$key];
    }
}
```

And (hopefully) stores data in it.

**Problem**

When I try to call the `get()` method in the `RoadTaxDataParser` in my `index.php` file like this:

```
echo RoadTaxDataParser::get('test');
```

I get an error saying:

> Notice: Undefined index: test in
>   C:\Users\Bas\Documents....\Cars\RoadTaxDataParser.php on line 13

**Expected result**

I hoped I can store data via the HTTP request in a sort of Registry class, and then get the data later on when i need it.

The purpose of this is that i dont want to do any calculations or html deployment with JavaScript, i want to do this with PHP.

**Question**

How can I store data in a class from a JavaScript HTTP request and then calling it back with your `index.php` file?

**My own try**

I tried it how Axel told me, with sessions. Like this in my `install.php` file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$road_tax_data = json_decode($_POST['road-tax_data'], true);
$_SESSION['rtd'] = $road_tax_data;
```

And then via my `index.php`:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['rtd']);
```

This gave me this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in
>   C:\Users\Bas\Documents...
>   .\Cars\index.php on line 26 NULL

Comment: As I understand, you are trying to keep the values between two PHP files, install.php and index.php, which get called each one after the other?

Comment: @AxelAmthor Yeah, because i dont want to do any calculation or deployment to the website with JavaScript.

Comment: Got it. There's no such thing like an instant application server with PHP. After execution of a script, the memory gets cleared and the instance of your `RoadTaxDataParser` is gone. In the next script, you get a frehs new empty `RoadTaxDataParser`. In order to achieve this, either use $_SESSION or something like memcache or APC.

Comment: @AxelAmthor Can you explain this in a question? Because i dont really get it  :)

Comment: You need to start a session first in every script: `session_start();` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php - as the first statement!

Comment: @AxelAmthor That did it, thank you :) Can you please edit that into your answer so i can accept it? Also, how can i make it so that the data is not based on a specific time before it disappears again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67790/discussion-between-bas-and-axel-amthor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing like an instant application server with PHP.

Each and every script needs to load the entire application context in to memory again and again. That's the great disadvantage of PHP.

If you have an object, storing context values, like your RoadTaxDataParser, you need to save the state, and within the next script, restore it, sinc after execution of a script, the memory gets cleared and the instance of your RoadTaxDataParser is gone.

You may do it like this, using the singleton design pattern (code not tested):

```
class RoadTaxDataParser
{
    public static $__instance = null;
    private static $data = [];

    public static function set ($key, $value) {
        self::$data[$key] = $value;
        $_SESSION['rtdp'] = self;  // could be done better
    }

    public static function get ($key) {
        return self::$data[$key];
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
          if ( self::$__instance != null )
                 return self::$__instance;
          self::$__instance = isset($_SESSION['rtdp']) ? $_SESSION['rtdp'] : new RoadTaxDataParser();

          return self::$__instance;

}
```

and then

```
 RoadTaxDataParser::getInstance()->set('test', $road_tax_data);
```

Additionally, you need to start a session first in every script:

```
 session_start();
```

see php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php - as the first statement!

Actually, the object only needs to be synchronized in to the session when the script terminates and not every time a value is assigned. But this needs another handler, which complicates structure over here.

Comment: Thanks, but how long does a session last?

Comment: configurable in php.ini.

Comment: Is it based on a specific time or untill you refresh your page? Also, will this be an possibility to get the data defininitly stored in an array? In a different class instance?

Comment: session timeout gets reset on each request automatically. Where you store your data (array, object, ...) depends on your application logic. This is a generic way to have an "almost" persistant object between two requests, using a session.

Comment: I've tried this code, and this doesn't work. It still can't find the data